# My ASP.NET page is making postback on web server and not on local host

Tags: asp.net, ajax, postback

I have created a website in ASP.NET = www.vif-tech.com/BidsOnline

When I am running it on Localhost using Visual Studio 2008, its running perfectly without any postback because I am using Ajax Update Panels (where data is changing constantly). But when I am running from my web server i.e. www.vif-tech.com/BidsOnline, its making postbacks every seconds.

Even I tried changing connection string on my localhost and tried connecting to main database (not on my localhost), it's still making postbacks.

Is there some error in my DB or page ?

Comment: Furthermore the link you provided works just fine on my computer.

Comment: Jan! can you check now please ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are missing some configuration things in your web.config. Make sure your config file is the same on both your localhost and at your webhost (except for the connection strings).

Comment: Jan! you can check now. The counters were stopped that's why it was not making postback. Please check now and tell me what's wrong with it